# Composable keeps thinking that the list is empty despite api call success

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose

I'm making an api call to retrieve a list of earthquakes. The call is always successful and log shows that the first item in the earthquake list is present. But when I try to populate a lazycolumn with the result it always states that the list is empty... I have tried various ways to make it work but it always fails. What is the problem and what is the simplest and the most practical way to make it work ?

Inside a viewmodel :

```
private val _state = MutableStateFlow(emptyList<Earthquake>())
val state: StateFlow<List<Earthquake>>
get() = _state

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val earthquakes = getEarthquakeList()
        _state.value = earthquakes
    }
}

 private fun getEarthquakeList() : List<Earthquake>{
     var list: List<Earthquake> = emptyList()
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val apiService = ApiService.getInstance()
        try {
            val response = apiService.getEarthquakes()
            Log.d("Response", response.data[0].title)
            list = response.data
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        // never triggers as log above always shows a result in the logcat
        }
    }
     return list
}
```

Inside MainActivity :

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        MyAppTheme {
            test()
        }
    }

@Composable
    fun test() {
        val earthquakeViewModel = viewModel(EarthquakeViewModel::class.java)
        val state by earthquakeViewModel.state.collectAsState()
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
            if (state.isEmpty()) {
                item {
                    CircularProgressIndicator(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center)
                    )
                }
            } else {
                items(state) { earthquake: Earthquake ->
                    Text(text = earthquake.title)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While I always get a proper result in the LogCat from the log in the viewmodel (example : D/Response: M 1.6 - 7km NW of The Geysers, CA), my screen forever shows the progress indicator ..
Curiously I do get two weird warnings in the log :

```
E/arthquakeap: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.example.earthquakeapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/dexopt/baseline.prof': No such file or directory
E/arthquakeap: Failed to open file '/data/data/com.example.earthquakeapp/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/assets/dexopt/baseline.prof': No such file or directory
```

Comment: the state is observing a standard Kotlin `list` `MutableStateFlow(emptyList<Earthquake>())`, the system doesn't care about the internal changes of an ordinary list `_state.value = earthquakes`, it will only (you can say react to changes) when the actual list has been changed `_state.value = _state.value.toList()` or `_state.value = mutableListOf().addAll(_state.value)`, basically creating a new `reference` that can wake up the system to trigger a `recomposition`

Comment: or you can simply use a `SnapshotStateList` that can always notify the `recomposition` that its internal state has changed. 

`val stateList = mutableStateListOf<Earthquake>()
        stateList.add(someEarthQuake) // will trigger recomposition 
`